# Issue with npm run dev command in vite project in windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, vue.js, npm, vite

I have found issues in running a Vue project with Vite  (both in the case of new projects and old projects). each time I run `npm run dev` or other npm commands, I get the following problem:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run dev

> my-app@0.0.0 dev
> vite

failed to load config from C:\Users\location\to\prject\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: The service was stopped
    at C:\Users\location\to\prject\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1083:25
    at responseCallbacks.<computed (C:\Users\location\to\prject\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:703:9)
    at Socket.afterClose (C:\Users\location\to\prject\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:693:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I am using windows 10, with node `v18.16.0` and npm `v9.5.1`, here is my `packages.json` content

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pinia": "^2.1.4",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4",
    "vuetify": "^3.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.6"
  }
}
```

I have found a workaround solution by deleting the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling packages each time I want to start the project, however, it's not a good way to reinstall packages every time, thus, I want help resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you share the content of your vite.config.js file ? That might help.

Comment: Is the port perhaps already in use? Please share your vite config.

Comment: Yes, deleting the `node_modules` folder and then running the command `npm install` resolves the issue.